# Get youtube trends v3 country wise in Json - Return Only 4 Videos

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I use following URL to get trending videos country wise.

But it returns only 4 videos. What is the reason for it?

Can't I get at least 10 videos?

Comment: what is the url you called?

Comment: @chinglun I think this is the URL `https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=contentDetails&chart=mostPopular&regionCode=IN&key=API_KEY`

Comment: What value did you put in the maxResults parameter? maxResults specifies the maximum number of items that should be returned in the result with range value of 0-50.

Answer (score 1):

I did a [try it](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list#try-it) dry run for mostpopular videos in your region (IN) and it seems it's working fine. I got a result of 50 videos out of the `"totalResults": 200,`.

Try this:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet&chart=mostPopular&maxResults=50&regionCode=IN&key=SERVER_API_KEY_HERE
```

If you want to access the remaining 50+ videos, just use the `nextPageToken`. Hope this helps you.